# Facebook apprequest implementation on iOS - accepted requests are opening app store, not my app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

In my application I have implemented apprequest refrenced from this url http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/

My problem is this when I send apprequest to my friends, after that he got notification from this and click notification then its redirect to iTunes app url where he download the app. After complete this procedure, again I send apprequest to my friends, my friend got notification like before and click this notification but it's redirecting to itunes not launching installed apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure the URL scheme correctly in your app's plist file? 
See Step 5 of [the iOS SDK 3.1 'Getting Started' guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) for more details on how to set the `FacebookAppID` and `URL types` values in your `.plist`

Without that, the Facebook app can't detect that your app is installed on the device, and directs to the App Store instead

Comment: I am not using facebook sdk ios, what should I do next please

Comment: Hey lgy, can you describe bit more,I am also stuck in same issue.

Comment: What do you mean by describe it a bit more? Step 5 of the tutorial should be clear on how to configure your app to work with Facebook login